# Коллежский/колледжский

Tags: орфография, лексика, словообразование, прилагательные

Прилагательное от слова *колледж* — *коллежский* или *колледжский*?

Comment: В Центре проходят обучение 32 студента РГГУ и 20 слушателей колледжной группы.

Comment: Коллегийный и Коллежный, ая, ое (1, 2). О вахмистрах, и коллегийных сторожах. ГР 33. И стол при котором Коллежные члены сидят, добрым сукном покрыт. ГР 18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• [Колле́жский](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) (устар.) — прилагательное от слова "коллегия" (советник, асессор, регистратор, секретарь, протоколист).

*По старинной табели о рангах он находился внизу, чиновник XIV класса — фендрик, **коллежский регистратор*** (Даниил Гранин. Зубр).

••  **На сегодня** в словарях прилагательное от слова "колледж" не зафиксировано.

> [Вопрос № 266770](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6&start=15#:%7E:text=%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%3F-,%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0,%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%22%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B.)
> Подскажите, пожалуйста, как образовать правильно прилагательное от слова **колледж**?
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> В литературном языке прилагательные от слова "колледж" неупотребительны.

Но иногда употребляются такие: "колледжский", "колледжный" и "колледжевый" (редко).

*...светлейшие головы из 60 лучших универов и колледжей страны замутили конторку, которая позже стала называться NCAA — Национальная Ассоциация **Колледжского** Спорта* (Янки спорт (2004) // «Хулиган», 15.06.2004).

*...Митчелл написала «Унесенных» после того, как в 1932-м вышел новый перевод «Карениной», и она вошла в ее **колледжную** программу* (М. Л. Гаспаров. Записи и выписки (2001)).

...*штрафы, которыми толстомордые **колледжевые** швейцары в котелках грозили, скажем, за гулянье по мураве, — просто традиционная шутка* (В. В. Набоков. Другие берега [переработанный автоперевод с английского] (1954)).

Comment: Рим, как до тебя достучаться-то?..

Comment: Артём, "дык" я вроде уже дала  дополнительные разъяснения (в дополнительном ответе о фараре — можно сказать, персонально для тебя)... Удивлялась я тогда тому, что твой вопрос оценили, в том числе и я (*получить два плюсика* — +20 баллов), и дали ответы, а ты сразу же посчитал лучшим свой собственный, никак не поддержав ответивших. Да и сейчас удивляюсь...

Comment: Я же просил ответа на комментарий под вопросом! Нельзя же отвечать только на часть того, что тебе пишут. Как это я не поддержал? Всех поддержал. И я там написал, что мой ответ лучше, а его даже никто не поддержал, удивляюсь, довелось дать себе же ответ впервые и никто не оценил.

Comment: Посчитаем, что я "переразобиделась". И исправилась. Пусть всё будет мирово.

Comment: Я просто тогда тоже разобиделся.)) Такому хорошему моему ответу не дали ничего, а другим и я дал, и остальные.

Comment: Рим, это ты проголосовала за мой ответ?!

Comment: Конечно же ж!.. "Переразобиделась" и исправилась.

Comment: )))) Спасибо! Тогда я выберу его, чтобы тебе было приятно. ;) А проголосовал я за два ответа на следующий день или через день.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Чаще надо голосовать, вот и всё, а не обижаться (непродуктивно это и вредно).  Год уж близится к концу, а ты всего 22 голоса отдал – как-то совсем уж мало, чтобы кому-то что-то предъявлять.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: я ничего не предъявляю, просто расстроился, что за мой хороший ответ вообще никто не проголосовал тогда. И если мой ответ мне больше нравится, что плохого, что я его выбираю? И откуда у меня возьмётся много голосов, если я вообще очень редко читаю новые вопросы и ответы? Из того, с чем я ознакомляюсь, это большая доля, просто мало читаю ответов. А как ты смотришь, сколько я голосов отдаю когда, Саш?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  [Участники – голосующие – год](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year).

Comment: Спасибо! А по поводу остального что скажешь? Я даже и не обижаюсь особенно, пока есть диалог, а когда на твой комментарий не отвечают или только на часть, не очень приятно, особенно при том, что телефона нету. Я сейчас тебя не имею в виду, переспросил и сейчас уверен, что день-два-три не придётся ждать, а гораздо быстрее. :)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да нечего уже особо говорить. Просто вопрос был: "Кто такой фарар?", и были даны хорошие ответы: "Священник (чешский)".

Comment: Но я же первый ответил себе, и логика была хорошая ответа. Перевёл кусочек чешской статьи из Википедии на английский в гугле, потом обобщил это по-русски. И уже всё понял. Такая редкость — себе же ответить! Хотелось награды. А про то, что я мало вообще читаю ответов, вопросов, поэтому не за что и голосовать мне, что скажешь?

Comment: Ладно, понятно уже всё, вроде "разобрались". А сколько кому читать и голосовать – дело личное. Я уже себе давал обещание не вмешиваться в это, и вот опять... :))

Comment: Личное не личное, а интересно твоё мнение. А почему *разобрались* в кавычках? И ещё повторюсь: меня больше всего расстраивает, что некоторые отвечают на мои комментарии через раз и лично я никого не знаю, не могу позвонить спросить и приходится ждать днями. О, кто-то ещё поддержал тот ответ (это ты, наверно :D) — спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Сначала написал без, как обычно, потом посчитал, что слово не совсем подходит, а сейчас опять думаю, что не нужны кавычки. "Вот такая я вся внезапная..." // Да, я.

Comment: Ха, не очень давно смотрел "Покровские ворота", но не вспомнил. Поделишься мнением о голосовании? Можешь ещё о чём-то. По-дружески о себе, не надо напирать, что я что-то не так делаю. Ведь чем больше обсуждений человеческих, тем больше я прислушиваюсь. И стараюсь сделать хорошо по своей воле, а не когда говорят, что я такой-сякой. :)) Чужой хороший пример он и так заразителен в хорошем смысле. Но пока не расскажешь, всё равно не буду представлять. Проблема в том, что на этом сайте этот хороший пример часто незаметен.

Comment: Дело в том, что мы даже не видим друг друга, а мне было бы интересно познакомиться со старожилами, в том числе и с Бегемотусом и Alexan_der-ом, которые пропали отсюда по, боюсь, единственной причине...

Comment: Да, согласен с тобой, но этот сайт как раз и не предназначен для такого общения. Может, и поделюсь... как-нибудь... когда-нибудь... Привет-пока!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: всё-таки интересно, Саш, в каком случае, по-твоему, можно выбрать свой ответ (если он не единственный)?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ну, исключаем, конечно, ошибочные, неясные и неграмотные. Если свой ответ полностью удовлетворяет запрос и интерес, то почему бы не выбрать его, тем более что он был дан за два часа до остальных. (Хотя, по-моему, в нём нет именно о "чехословацком" использовании.)

Answer (score 2):

Вариант относительного  прилагательного еще не нормирован в словарях. Какие же варианты представляются здесь **возможными**?

Попробуем составить перечень: ***коллежский, колледжский, колледжный, колледжевый.***   Суффиксы: *-СК, -ЕВ, -Н.*

Основа слова "колледж" на два согласных ***-ДЖ***, а это не очень хорошо. Здесь  возможно **стечение** согласных, неудобных для произношения.

Суффикс ***ЕВ*** (на гласную) в этом отношении хорош, но он хуже подходит **по семантике**.

Суффикс ***ОВ/ЕВ*** близок к притяжательному значению (*отцов*), также вы видим его в словах *сосновый, ситцевый, тигровый, карликовый, шариковый* и т.д.  К названию учебного заведения он плохо подходит.

Суффикс ***СК*** использован в словах ***институтский, университетский***, но  сочетание ***ДЖСК***  очень неудобно для произношения.  Использовать усечение основы?  Но существовало слово "коллежский", основу не хотелось бы искажать.

Тогда остается суффикс ***-Н***: ***колледжный***. Кстати, он используется в  слове *«школьный».*

Пример: *В Центре проходят обучение 32 студента РГГУ и 20 слушателей **колледжной** группы.*

**P.S.** Для сравнения: котте**дж** – котте**дж**ный (поселок).

**КОЛЛЕЖСКИЙ**, -ая, -ое. Устар. 1. к Коллегия (3 зн.). 2. В России до 1917 г.: составная часть названий некоторых гражданских чинов. К. советник.